# pdfJsLib - Extract horizontal lines of a table

Tags: mozilla, pdfjs-dist

This pdf contains a table. I want to get the bounding horizontal line of this table. By line, I mean the graphical line (a straight line), and not a text line.

I tried getAnnotations but it returns empty array. I am using pdfjsLib in javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried using `pdfjsLib.OPS.reactangle` to get the lines/rectangle coordinates. While i could get the coordinates, these have to be transformed to the pdf axis. Which i am unable to figure how to do.